# How to sort a multidimensional array based on multiple criteria

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array I need to sort based on multiple criteria and I'm not sure what the optimal way to do that is.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
array {
  [0]=>
  array {
    ["itemid"]=>
    string "3135475"
    ["model"]=>
    array {
      ["Model"]=>
      string "MK1931"
    }
    ["brand"]=>
    array {
      ["Brand"]=>
      string "Castles"
      ["Manufacturer"]=>
      string "Castles Int'l, LTD"
    }
    ["views"]=>
    string "53465"
  }
  [1]=>
  array {
    ["itemid"]=>
    string "3616546"
    ["model"]=>
    array {
      ["Model"]=>
      string"1931"
      ["PartNumber"]=>
      string "MK1931"
    }
    ["brand"]=>
    array {
      ["Brand"]=>
      string "Castles"
      ["Manufacturer"]=>
      string "Castles Int'l, LTD"
    }
    ["views"]=>
    string "134465"
  }
  [2]=>
  array {
    ["itemid"]=>
    string "1024567"
    ["model"]=>
    array {
      ["PartNumber"]=>
      string "MK1931"
    }
    ["brand"]=>
    array {
      ["Brand"]=>
      string "Castles"
    }
    ["views"]=>
    string "253465"
  }
  [3]=>
  array {
    ["itemid"]=>
    string "35463810"
    ["model"]=>
    array {
      ["PartNumber"]=>
      string "MK1931-170952"
    }
    ["brand"]=>
    array {
      ["Brand"]=>
      string "Product By Castles"
    }
    ["views"]=>
    string "265"
  }
}
```

I need to find the itemid in the array that has both the highest # of brand matches to "Castles" and the highest # of model matches to "MK1931" and then out that I need the element with the highest # of views. If an element doesn't have any brand and model matches it should be discarded before even checking the views.

In this case, just eyeballing it, it would be element #2 (itemid 1024567).

I'm trying to figure out the fastest, least CPU intensive method of getting element #2 using PHP.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found array_multisort() function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: have you cjecked this?

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Comment: @goodmood Will check it out and see if I can adapt it.